# Azure-Powershell Enable File Service Encryption on storage account

Tags: powershell, azure

In Powershell.. How would i be able to create and/or modify a storage account that has encryption enabled for Blob and File Service?

I'm using the following code to enable the Blob service encryption but cannot figure out how to set the File service encryption.

```
$storageResult = New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $groupName -Name $accountName -Location $location -EnableEncryptionService Blob -Kind $accountKind -SkuName $replicationType
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the command to enable encryption on Azure file service:

```
Set-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -AccountName "MyStorageAccount" -EnableEncryptionService "File"
```

Comment: Thank you, i have tried that but i get an error message : Set-AzureRmStorageAccount : Cannot bind parameter 'EnableEncryptionService'. Cannot convert value "File" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.StorageAccountBaseCmdlet+EncryptionSupportServiceEnum". Error: "Unable to 
match the identifier name File to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:
Blob"

Comment: Got a feeling it could be versions of the modules

Comment: I am able to run the command successfully in my lab. can you update your PowerShell to latest module and retry the operation.                                             https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM/4.4.0